# How to remove http POST data on the client-side

Tags: http, netlify, strapi

I'm creating a web app using Vuejs as the frontend and Strapi as the backend. Frontend and backend are hosted on different location (e.g Frontend on Netlify and backend on VPS) and communicate by REST API.
Now I'm developing a payment feature for this app. The scenario is:

- client (frontend) will be directed to gateway (external link)
- gateway will redirect user to the client with http POST data (URL is something like exmaple.com/#/verifyPayment)

I don't need this POST data because I will verify the payment later using an inquiry api request.
My problem is that the Frontend (here Vue) can not handle the post and instead of showing the normal route (/verifyPayment) shows an HTML page with **Cannot POST /** content.
Note that I have no control on the gateway. So, *I need a way to get rid of this POST data and let Vue router acts its normal behavior.*

Comment: Doubt you can get around providing the gateway with a valid endpoint to send their post to and subsequently redirect back to your vue app from there

Comment: I think what @charlietfl is saying is to provide an endpoint in your backend that accepts the POST request then redirects back to your VUE app via a GET request. A typical [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern